# $\mathcal{D}$-classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

Let $$\alpha = \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
1&3&3
\end{array}\right) \in \mathcal{T}_3\text{.}$$
(a) Show that the $\mathcal{D}$-class of $\alpha$ contains all those elements of $\mathcal{T}_3$ which have the same rank (cardinality of their image) as $\alpha$.

(b) Show that the $\mathcal{D}$-class of $\alpha$ contains 3 $\mathcal{R}$-classes and 3 $\mathcal{L}$-classes and that it has 2 element $\mathcal{H}$-classes.

How to do (b)?

From (a) we have that $D_{\alpha} = \{ \beta \in \mathcal{T}_3 : | \text{Im}( \beta )| = 2 \}$.

Explicitly then:

$$D_{\alpha} = \left\{ \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
1&1&2
\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
1&2&1
\end{array}\right) , \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
2&1&1
\end{array}\right) , \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
2&2&1
\end{array}\right) , \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
2&1&2
\end{array}\right) , \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
1&2&2
\end{array}\right) , \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
3&3&1
\end{array}\right) , \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
3&1&3
\end{array}\right) , \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
1&3&3
\end{array}\right) , \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
1&1&3
\end{array}\right) , \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
1&3&1
\end{array}\right) , \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
3&1&1
\end{array}\right) , \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
2&2&3
\end{array}\right) , \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
2&3&2
\end{array}\right) , \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
3&2&2
\end{array}\right) , \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
3&3&2
\end{array}\right) , \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
3&2&3
\end{array}\right) , \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
2&3&3
\end{array}\right) \right\}$$

Comment: It would help if you told us what $\mathcal T_3$ is and what $\mathcal{D, R, L, H}$-classes are.

Comment: $\mathcal{T}_3$ is the full transformation semigroup (set of all maps from a set $X$ to itself). $\mathcal{D}$, $\mathcal{R}$, $\mathcal{L}$, $\mathcal{H}$ are Green's relations:$$a\;\mathcal{L}\; b \iff S^1a = S^1b \;\;\;\;\forall \;\;a,b\in S\text{.}$$ $$a\;\mathcal{R}\; b \iff aS^1 = bS^1 \;\;\;\;\forall \;\;a,b\in S\text{.}$$ $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{L} \cap \mathcal{R}$.$$a\; \mathcal{D}\;b \iff \exists \; c\in S\;\text{st}\;a\;\mathcal{R}\;c\;\mathcal{L}\;b$$ $R_{\alpha}$ is the $\mathcal{R}$-class of $\alpha\in S,\;D_{\alpha}$ is the $\mathcal{D}$-class of $\alpha$, etc.

Comment: Sorry: $\mathcal{T}_3$ is the set of all maps $\alpha : \{ 1,2,3\} \to \{ 1,2,3 \}$

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I removed the group-theory and inverse semigroups tags.  Since the ${\cal T_3}$ is neither a group nor an inverse semigroup, they didn't seem appropriate.

Comment: @Jim:  People likely to help with this question would know those definitions, so I don't think it's necessary to provide them.

Comment: @TaraB: I didn't expect him to write out the definition if it's standard; just giving the name "Green's relations" would be enough.  Semigroups are not so complicated that we should expect it to be impossible to answer a question on them after looking at the definition of the relations.

Comment: @Jim:  Fair enough.  Well, I wouldn't agree with 'semigroups are not so complicated', but certainly basic semigroup theory isn't.

Comment: Wow... all those arrays. Why not use `\begin{pmatrix}` and save all that trouble?

Answer (score 1):

So you're fine with a)?  By the way, this is a special case of a more general fact: the ${\cal D}$-classes in a full transformation semigroup are always the sets of all transformations with a given rank.

For b), try playing around with the elements of the ${\cal D}$-class to find out when they are ${\cal R}$- or ${\cal L}$-related.  Hint:  it has something to do with images and kernels.

In response to your question below:  Okay, so you already knew the thing I was hinting at.  An ${\cal R}$-class is just an equivalence class under the relation ${\cal R}$.  So you need to show that there are are three different possible kernels and three different possible images for elements of ${\cal D}_\alpha$.

Comment: I'm fine with (a). Two elements of $\mathcal{T}_3$ are $\mathcal{R}$ related if and only if they have the same kernel and they're \mathcal{L} related if and only if they have the same image. I think I can find the elements of $R_{\alpha}$, $L_{\alpha}$ and $H_{\alpha}$ using that. What does it mean by saying show that $D_{\alpha}$ contains 3 $\mathcal{R}$-classes etc?

Comment: I edited my answer in response to your comment.  Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I've had to change accounts as I can't access my email account so I can't reply to any posts because I'm not using the account I originally asked the question from!

So:

$\beta \in R_{\alpha} \iff \text{Ker}(\beta)$ has classes $\{1\},\{2,3\}$ and $\beta \in L_{\alpha} \iff \text{Im}(\beta) = \{1,3\}$

$$R_{\alpha} = \left\{ \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
1&2&2
\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
2&1&1
\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
1&3&3
\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
3&1&1
\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
2&3&3
\end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{@{\,}c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\;\; }c@{\,}}
1&2&3\\
3&2&2
\end{array}\right) \right\}$$

Comment: This is correct.  Now what are the other ${\cal R}$- and ${\cal L}$-classes in ${\cal D}_\alpha$, and what are the ${\cal H}$-classes?

Comment: I've just posted what I think the elements of $R_{\alpha}$ are above (I had to post as an answer due to the character limit). How do you know how to separate these into 3 $\mathcal{R}$-classes?

Comment: It's ${\cal D}_\alpha$ that you want to separate into three ${\cal R}$-classes.  So $R_\alpha$ is one of them.  What are the other two?  You know that ${\cal R}$-classes are determined by the kernel of the transformations, so what are the other possible kernels for elements in ${\cal D}_\alpha$?

Comment: What is the definition of the kernel? What is the kernel of the elements of $R_{\alpha}$?

Comment: For a transformation $\alpha: X\to Y$, $\ker(\alpha)$ is the equivalence relation on $X$ given by $x\sim y$ iff $x\alpha = y\alpha$.  So the kernel of the elements of $R_\alpha$ is $\ker(\alpha)$, which is { {1}, {2,3}}, as you pretty much said in your answer.

Comment: So the other possible kernels of elements of $D_{\alpha}$ are $\{\{1,2\},\{3\}\}$ and $\{\{1,3\},\{2\}\}$

Comment: That's right.  So that lets you conclude there are three ${\cal R}$-classes.  Now do the same thing with images for the ${\cal L}$-classes.  Hmm, it's asking me to move this to chat now, but you can't chat because you need 20 rep or something.

Comment: The 3 possible images of elements of $D_{\alpha}$ are $\{1,2\}$, $\{2,3\}$ and $\{1,3\}$ so $D_\alpha$ contains 3 $\mathcal{L}$-classes. Now the $\mathcal{H}$-classes are the intersections of the $\mathcal{R}$-classes and the $\mathcal{L}$-classes. The 3 $\mathcal{R}$-classes each contain 6 elements and the 3 $\mathcal{L}$-classes each contain 6 elements. There are then 9 $\mathcal{H}$-classes each containing 2 elements.

Comment: You should probably state that you are using the fact that all the ${\cal H}$-classes in a ${\cal D}$-class have the same size.  Right, all sorted then!  You could put this all into your answer and accept it.